# pg_restore into a different table structure?

Tags: postgresql, restore, database-backups, pg-restore

- I have two different databases containing a table called ***feed_items***
- Lets call them source and destination.
- I want to copy some 250k rows from the source feed_items table to the destination feed_items table

**Structure of source feed_items table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.feed_items
(
    feed_item_id uuid NOT NULL,
    pubdate timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    link character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    guid character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    title text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    summary text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    content text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    author character varying(63) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    feed_id integer NOT NULL,
    tags character varying(127)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" DEFAULT '{}'::character varying[],
    title_vector tsvector,
    summary_vector tsvector,
    CONSTRAINT feed_items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (feed_item_id),
    CONSTRAINT fkey_feed_item_feed FOREIGN KEY (feed_id)
        REFERENCES public.feeds (feed_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.feed_items
    OWNER to ch_v3_root;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_feed_items_pubdate_feed_item_id_desc
    ON public.feed_items USING btree
    (pubdate DESC NULLS FIRST, feed_item_id DESC NULLS FIRST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_summary_vector
    ON public.feed_items USING gin
    (summary_vector)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_tags_array
    ON public.feed_items USING gin
    (tags COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_title_vector
    ON public.feed_items USING gin
    (title_vector)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE TRIGGER on_insert_feed_items
    AFTER INSERT
    ON public.feed_items
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.notify_change_feed_items();

CREATE TRIGGER on_update_feed_items
    AFTER UPDATE 
    ON public.feed_items
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (new.title <> old.title OR new.summary <> old.summary OR new.content <> old.content)
    EXECUTE FUNCTION public.notify_change_feed_items();

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_summary_vector
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON public.feed_items
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION tsvector_update_trigger('summary_vector', 'pg_catalog.english', 'summary');

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_update_title_vector
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE 
    ON public.feed_items
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION tsvector_update_trigger('title_vector', 'pg_catalog.english', 'title');
```

**Structure of the destination feed_items table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.feed_items
(
    id uuid NOT NULL,
    author character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    content text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    guid character varying(2047) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    link character varying(2047) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    pubdate timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    searchable tsvector GENERATED ALWAYS AS (((setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(title, (''::character varying)::text)), 'A'::"char") || setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(summary, ''::text)), 'B'::"char")) || setweight(to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, COALESCE(content, (''::character varying)::text)), 'C'::"char"))) STORED,
    summary text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    tags character varying(255)[] COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL DEFAULT (ARRAY[]::character varying[])::character varying(255)[],
    title text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    feed integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT feed_items_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT feed_items_link_key UNIQUE (link),
    CONSTRAINT feed_items_feed_fkey FOREIGN KEY (feed)
        REFERENCES public.feeds (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE CASCADE
        ON DELETE CASCADE
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS public.feed_items
    OWNER to ch_api_user;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS feed_items_pubdate_id
    ON public.feed_items USING btree
    (pubdate DESC NULLS FIRST, id DESC NULLS FIRST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS feed_items_searchable
    ON public.feed_items USING gin
    (searchable)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS feed_items_tags
    ON public.feed_items USING gin
    (tags COLLATE pg_catalog."default")
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

The names of a few columns have changed, the order of columns has changed and the table is assigned to a different database user. How do I pg_restore from source to destination?

Comment: You cannot use `pg_dump`/`pg_restore` for that. Write two appropriate `COPY` statements.

Comment: Please don't post the same question in multiple forums.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe sorry about that, I deleted the other post

Comment: Use `pg_dump ... -t feed_items -a ` to get data only dump of the source table. This will be in the form of  a `COPY`. Modify the column names to the new versions. Order does not matter as the `COPY` will match the column names in the file to those in the table.